# Loading contents dynamically

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have product listing page, which displays all the products which satisfy the search criteria. And these could be any number of products.

What I want is something like FB, that I display only first 5-7 products and as the user scrolls down, the products should be loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider switching to jQuery or Mootools as JS libraries if you want to do this - both have native support for the **infinite scroller** concept as it's commonly called. It's not that hard to implement yourself though, mainly a matter of keeping track what you loaded last, and installing an `onScroll` event to detect when the bottom of the page is reached.

[Here's a good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/) using native JS to implement it, both server and client side. You'll need to replace the XHR invocations by the proper Prototype alternatives yourself (or not, wouldn't really matter).